# What is devops?

Tags: culture

What is devops?  It has something to do with combining dev and ops but I don't get it.

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This article might help.. https://medium.com/@neonrocket/devops-is-a-culture-not-a-role-be1bed149b0

Comment: Check this topic on "What is not DevOps?", this clarify certain aspects for common misunderstandings
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cjAg1dUO8A&t=408s&ab_channel=BribeByBytes

Answer (score 20):

It's not about "combining" Dev and Ops, that's just the word for it as, I think, it was [coined by Patrick Debois](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2010/02/12/what-is-this-devops-thing-anyway/). As stated above, it's about providing the scaffolding or structure, and the cultural change to accept intermingling of Dev-side and Ops-side talent, to allow you bridge the DevOps gap. What they used to call "over the wall" or "over the transom" delivery of application code to IT to "take it live."

This wasn't a big problem when you had one gonzo big release every 12 months or so. With Agile Methodology and with cloud infrastructure, however, you can now have releases occurring every couple of weeks and into a (private or public) cloud where things can get complex fast. [Flickr did a presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jallspaw/10-deploys-per-day-dev-and-ops-cooperation-at-flickr) earlier this year where they can do 10+ releases in a day! That rams a very large workload onto QA and Ops. DevOps refers to the movement and the recognition of the need for planning, coordination and automation tooling that has some Dev components and Ops components.

Answer (score 16):

It's not exactly combining Dev and Ops, but rather providing the platform, tools, knowledge, and resources for these two teams to work better together. With the increase of agile development, IT operations have become a bottle neck in most organizations, and are not capable of deploying applications into the data center on-time and error-free. There is a lot of movement around application release automation (such as Nolio ASAP), and provisioning automation (Puppet, Chef, etc.).

Answer (score 13):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps#cite_note-0):

> DevOps is a set of processes, methods
>   and systems for communication,
>   collaboration and integration between
>   departments for Development
>   (Applications/Software Engineering),
>   Technology Operations and Quality
>   Assurance (QA)

Answer (score 4):

It's really a culture, or a cultural movement, aimed at removing the barriers between developers and operators (a distinction that tends to be more rarified as technologies like cloud computing, continuous delivery and mass/automated deployment are getting mature and mainstream). If you call yourself a "DevOps", you're doing it wrong!

Comment: You're right. I would also mention the new set of tools used by DevOps professional to give a glance on what skillset it requires.

Comment: This is the best answer at this point. It also raises on of the key issues. Its all about culture change. If you do not address the culture piece first, the tools are irrelevant. https://youtu.be/MqruGJKdBLs